# Making a tree structure in django models?

Tags: python, django, activerecord, django-models

I want to have a model with 2 fields, children and parent. How do I do this in django? I have something like this

```
from django.db import models
class FooModel(models.Model)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    children = models.ManyToOneRel('self', blank=True, null=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parent.children.add(self)
```

But I don't think i'm supposed to use the ManyToOneRel like this (especially because it's giving me a keyword error on 'blank'). Any advice?

Comment: https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/

Comment: These are both nice, but is it possible to do it directly in the fields like I'm trying to do above? I'd rather not include another dependency in this, and I don't care about efficiency that much in this case.

Comment: why use `ManyToOneRel` ? you are just duplicating information, with `parent` you could use the relation backwards to find its childs

Comment: Ok, I guess I care a little about efficiency. I would like to cache the children for a given parent, so I can easily get them from a model instand without searching through the whole database.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`ManyToOneRel` is an internal implementation class, it's not for use in your models.

But why do you think you need it anyway? As the documentation explains in detail, when you define a ForeignKey, you automatically get a reverse relation. So in your case, if you define `parent` then you automatically get `self.foomodel_set` already: and you can make it even more explicit by using the `related_name` parameter:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
```

Note that if you're planning on doing complicated things with trees, you probably want to be using the [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

Answer (score 3):

```
class FooModel(models.Model)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')


FooModel.objects.get(pk=1).children.all()
```

If you wish to cache use whatever you want: caching of query somewhere, store all children in parent as a flat list of pks, but don't forget to handle new entities to update this list. ManyToOneRel is for internal needs of django moreover it isn't an instance of Field class.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the documentation for `ManyToOneRel` so I looked up the [code for it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L922):

```
def __init__(self, to, field_name, related_name=None, limit_choices_to=None,
        parent_link=False, on_delete=None):
```

As you can see, there is no `blank` argument.

Comment: Right, I've already figured that out. I'm wondering what I should be using instead.

Comment: maybe just use a CharField to store the keys of the children and a custom method or property to instantiate them on request?